# Pyscript「エラー500(Internal Server Error)」

Tags: python, html

https://pyscript.net/examples/simple_clock.html
https://pyscript.net/examples/utils.py
をPCにダウンロードし、実行すると動作します。しかし、サーバーにアップロードすると、以下のようなエラーが発生します。

(PY0500): Fetching from URL ./utils.py failed with error 500 (Internal Server Error). Are your filename and path correct?

サーバーで動くようにするにはどうしたらいいでしょうか。

simple_clock.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />

    <title>Simple Clock Demo</title>

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css"
    />

    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/examples.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar" style="background-color: #000000">
        <div class="app-header">
            <a href="/">
                <img src="./logo.png" class="logo" />
            </a>
            <a class="title" href="" style="color: #f0ab3c">Simple Clock</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <section class="pyscript">
        <div class="font-mono">
            start time: <label id="outputDiv"></label>
        </div>
        <div id="outputDiv2" class="font-mono"></div>
        <div id="outputDiv3" class="font-mono"></div>

        <py-tutor modules="utils.py">
            <py-config>
                plugins = [
                  "https://pyscript.net/latest/plugins/python/py_tutor.py"
                ]
                [[fetch]]
                files = ["./utils.py"]
            </py-config>
            <py-script>
                import utils
                display(utils.now())
            </py-script>

            <py-script>
                from utils import now
                import asyncio

                async def foo():
                  while True:
                    await asyncio.sleep(1)
                    output = now()
                    Element("outputDiv2").write(output)

                    out3 = Element("outputDiv3")
                    if output[-1] in ["0", "4", "8"]:
                      out3.write("It's espresso time!")
                    else:
                      out3.clear()

                pyscript.run_until_complete(foo())
            </py-script>
        </py-tutor>
    </section>
</body>
```

utils.py

```
from datetime import datetime as dt


def format_date(dt_, fmt="%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S"):
    return f"{dt_:{fmt}}"


def now(fmt="%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S"):
    return format_date(dt.now(), fmt)


def remove_class(element, class_name):
    element.element.classList.remove(class_name)


def add_class(element, class_name):
    element.element.classList.add(class_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

サーバーの設定を変えたら動作しました。
It works after change the server setting.

```
Web server (centos 7 )
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

01:
<Directory "/var/www/html">
AllowOverride None
</Directory>
02:
<IfModule mime_module>
#AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
</IfModule>
```

Comment: 当サイトは日本語でのやり取りを基本としているので、英語の併記は不要です。